# Getting an error and I can't see what

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Keep getting an error when i try to create a new object by pressing a button. Help and an Explanation would be appreciate  my guess is that theres a rouge () somehere? or somthing else what is easy to spot but im not seeing it

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
int GWIDTH = 400;
int GHEIGHT = 300;

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

int x,y;
int rectX, rectY;
int random;

boolean mouseOnScreen;
boolean mouseDragged;

int click = 0;
int Resource = 0;
int ore = 100; 

int mx, my;


public Main(){

    setSize(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
    setTitle("Game");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addMouseListener(new Mouse());



    frame(dbg);



    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    random = 100;

}

private void frame(Graphics g) {
     JFrame f = new JFrame();
     f.setVisible(true);
     f.setSize(400, 400);

     JPanel p = new JPanel();
     JButton b1 = new JButton("New ore");
     JButton b2 = new JButton("New worker");
     JButton b3 = new JButton("Upgrade pick");
     JButton b4 = new JButton("Turret");
     JButton b5 = new JButton("Barrack");
     b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Succses!");
             System.out.println(Resource-=ore);
             Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(300, 50, 50, 50);
             g.setColor(Color.RED);
             g.fillRect(r3.x, r3.y, r3.width, r3.height);
         }
     });
     p.add(b1);
     p.add(b2);
     p.add(b3);
     p.add(b4);
     p.add(b5);
     f.add(p);
}

public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        click += e.getClickCount();
        rectX = e.getX();
        rectY = e.getY();
        y = rectY;
        x = rectX;

        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, 7, 7);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(175, 75, 50, 50);





        if(r1.intersects(r2))
        Resource += e.getClickCount();






    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        mouseOnScreen = true;

        rectX = e.getX();
        rectY = e.getY();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        mouseOnScreen = false;
        rectX = e.getX();
        rectY = e.getY();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        click += e.getClickCount();
        rectX = e.getX();
        rectY = e.getY();

        mouseDragged = true;


        e.consume();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        rectX = e.getX();
        rectY = e.getY();


        e.consume();
    }
}



    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval(x, y, 7, 7);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("Clicks ("+click+")", 40, 40);

    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, 7, 7);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(175, 75, 50, 50);
    Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(300, 50, 50, 20);



    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);








        g.drawString("Resources:("+Resource+")", 40, 50);


    repaint();
}







public static void main (String[] args) {
   Main main = new Main();
}
}
```

Here's my error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:80)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What's this? `System.out.println(Resource-=ore);` Just follow the line numbers referenced in the stack trace.

Comment: Most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should inspect the line carefully that throws the exception**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: @Julian, a compound statement? user..., looks like you have a `null` culprit on line 80. Go see what it is.

Comment: Your use of java.awt.Graphics is questionable, as you're using a Graphics field in you class, a dangerous thing to do. By the way, which line is line 80 of your code above?

Comment: Also, if you need help figuring it out, **please do something in your post to indicate which line is line 80**.  I am not going to start counting lines in your program to figure out which line is line 80.  (And posters often remove extra comments or only post part of their code, so I'd have no way of knowing for sure whether my count gives the correct line.)

Comment: Now I dug deeper in your code and found out that you declared a variable with the name `Resource`. Never do that. Have variable names only begin with lowercase letters; uppercase is reserved for class names.

Comment: A single blank line of white space is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 3):

As I have suspected (see one of my comments to your original question), you are using a Graphics object incorrectly and are trying to draw with a null Graphics variable. Suggestions:

- Don't give your class a Graphics field and don't pass a Graphics object to your frame method as you're trying to do.
- Instead draw inside of the paintComponent method with the Graphics object given to you by the JVM.
- Or draw with a Graphics object that has been extracted from a BufferedImage or other image, but if you do this, be sure to dispose of the Graphics object when done with it.
- Again, most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should inspect the line carefully that throws the exception**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

---

- Also, don't call `repaint()` from within a paintComponent method as this is a very bad and uncontrolled way to try to do animation. Instead use a Swing Timer if you want simple animation.
- For more and better help, try giving us more detail on just what you're trying to do with this code.
- If your goal is to have one class add a new Rectangle to another class, give the second class an `addRectangle(Rectangle r)` method that the first class could call. Within that method, consider adding the parameter to an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` that is a field.
- Then iterate through the List when drawing Rectangles *and* when checking mouse clicks.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddRandomRects {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("AddRandomRects");

      MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      DialogPanelCreator dialogPanelCreator = new DialogPanelCreator(mainPanel);
      JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Create and Remove Rect Dialog", ModalityType.MODELESS);
      dialog.getContentPane().add(dialogPanelCreator.getMainComponent());
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
      dialog.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
   public static final int PREF_W = 800;
   public static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   public static final int RECT_WIDTH = 70;
   private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.RED;
   private static final Color RECT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
   private static final Stroke RECT_BORDER_STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);

   private List<Rectangle> rectList = new ArrayList<>();

   public MainPanel() {
      rectList.add(new Rectangle(100, 100, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_WIDTH));
   }

   public void addRectangle(int x, int y) {
      Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_WIDTH);
      rectList.add(r);
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      for (Rectangle rect : rectList) {
         g2.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
         g2.fill(rect);
         g2.setColor(RECT_BORDER_COLOR);
         g2.setStroke(RECT_BORDER_STROKE);
         g2.draw(rect);
      }
      g2.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public void removeLastRectangle() {
      if (rectList.size() > 0) {
         rectList.remove(rectList.size() - 1);
         repaint();
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DialogPanelCreator {
   private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   private MainPanel mainPanel;
   private Random random = new Random();

   public DialogPanelCreator(MainPanel mainPanel) {
      this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
      panel.add(new JButton(new AddRectangleAction("Add Rectangle", KeyEvent.VK_A)));
      panel.add(new JButton(new RemoveLastRectangleAction("Remove Last Rectangle", KeyEvent.VK_R)));
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return panel;            
   }

   private class AddRectangleAction extends AbstractAction {
      public AddRectangleAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         int x = random.nextInt(MainPanel.PREF_W - MainPanel.RECT_WIDTH);
         int y = random.nextInt(MainPanel.PREF_H - MainPanel.RECT_WIDTH);

         mainPanel.addRectangle(x, y);
      }
   }

   private class RemoveLastRectangleAction extends AbstractAction {
      public RemoveLastRectangleAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         mainPanel.removeLastRectangle();
      }
   }

}
```